# Scan formatted hard drive for ANSI txt file?

Tags: windows, ntfs

Is there any software that will allow me to undelete a text file encoded in ANSI? I know one line of the TXT file (so search would be useful). The hard drive was formatted using a quick format so the partition table has been destroyed but the content has not been overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

Boot up a linux live CD, and assuming `/dev/sda` is your formatted harddrive:

```
 sudo cat /dev/sda | grep -C 100 -i "The one line of text you rememeber" > ~/recovered.txt
```

This will find the string of text, and grab 100 lines before and after it, and then dump it into a text file in your home directory on the live CD.

Answer (score 0):

You might try [testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk). There are many tutorials on their site.